# Not possible to resize images to bigger sizes with Pillow?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, resize, python-imaging-library

It's seems that resizing to smaller sizes (thumbnails) works fine. However, resizing to bigger sizes does not work. Do you know why? What would you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: What error, if any, do you get?

Comment: I don't get any error. When it comes to down-scale it works without any problems. But when I try to up-scale it creates a copy of the same size instead of up-scaling...

Comment: ok, the problem was that I was not assigning the resized image to a new variable, but rather, I was saving the not-yet-resized image. sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### .resize() accepts tuple, be it a request to down-scale or to up-scale

works both directions

```
>>> from PIL import Image                                  # .INIT
>>> im = Image.open( "ColorLookUpTABLE___TEST_CHART.png" ) # .GET 258,200 [px]
>>> imB = im.resize( ( 516, 400 ) )                        # .SET 516,400 [px] a double
>>> imB                                                    # .CHK instance
<PIL.Image.Image image mode=P size=516x400 at 0x19D9968>
>>> imB.show()                                             # .GUI shown
```

[image]